# Access windows server with putty key

Tags: ssh, powershell, putty, openssh

I installed openssh both manualy with the powershell script and with OpenSSH for windows 8.3p1-1. It works both with purry and winSCP, but I'm not able to make putty work with a key.

I generated the key with putty gen than saved the private key and copied the public key in a file named authorized_keys without exetnsion in the user/.ssh folder I want to access to.

Once I uploaded the ppk and run the console putty alerts me that the server refused their key.

I also tried to load the key into pageant.exe, but it didn’t work too

Am I doing something wrong? thanks

Comment: The OpenSSH Server log should provide some insight into the problem.  Have you enabled verbose logging?

Comment: the public key goes in an authorized_keys on the server you're trying to connect to in the users account. It has to be a single line of 3 space-separated fields: the first has type of key like rsa or dsa, the 2nd is the public key data, 3rd is optional comment like email address. If I remember putty has its own key format which would have to be converted. Pagaent is the equivalent of an ssh-agent which holds private keys for connections.

Comment: @strobelight: the PuTTY suite uses its own format for _privatekey_ file (PPK = PuTTY Private Key) but Windows puttygen displays the _publickey_ in OpenSSH format. (Unix puttygen is commandline not GUI, and supports multiple formats per the man page.)

Comment: The public key is saved in the windows user folder in its own .ssh folder. The format of the public key is in OpenSSH, 3 spce separated field. Putty keep alerting “Server refused our key”. Where should I find a log report?

Comment: If you are logging in with administrator account, the key file is different. See https://superuser.com/q/1544120/213663